# List all values ​in each SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to make a generic listing that will bring me all the values, ​​I have in the bank, every bank line.

My application needs to read information that changes and transits in the bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display all tables values/data in your Database without writing a `select` statement for each table you can use below SQL:

Try like this:

```
DECLARE @sqlText VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlText = ''
SELECT @sqlText = @sqlText + ' SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + CHAR(13) FROM  sys.tables
EXEC(@sqlText)
```

Comment: Bank? what is this?  Database name or server name?